# Does lombok @Data generated setters perform deepcopy to member objects like maps?

Tags: java, lombok

I could not find any documentation on whether lombok generate setters that perform a clone or deep copy of the container params like lists/maps. Can someone confirm?

[lombok Getter/Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy enough to just test?

Comment: @CollinD Maybe for you, but wouldn't be better to answer how to test it, and show the test results for others who are learning?

Comment: I agree with @CollinD, it's quicker to either write a test or use your IDE "delombok" feature

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP can confirm by himself/herself

Comment: Answer is no.

see https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/781 and https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/150 for example.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as deep copy in Java. What should `Map<?, ?> map = makeMyMap(); this.map = deepCopy(map);` do? This can only work if the actual (rather than declared) type is known to lombok or if it can be cloned in custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a quick test shows that there is no deep copying going on (as expected, really, since reliably deep copying a variable of *any* possible type would be quite difficult/impossible(?) to work perfectly).

Lombok'd class

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    private Map<Object, Object> bar;
}
```

And to test

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Map<Object, Object> bar = new HashMap<>();
foo.setBar(bar);
bar.put("foo", "bar");
assert foo.getBar() == bar : "getBar() and bar do not share the same memory location (aren't the same object)";
assert foo.getBar().get("foo").equals("bar") : "Calls to put(...) aren't persisted after setBar(...) call.";
```

Note that these assertions all pass, so it is clear that the copy is a simple object reference rather than a deep copy.